# Mathematical function with input not in definition

Tags: functions, inverse

I have just come across a definition for a mathematical function where in the input is not part of the function definition.

This is a simplified variation of the function:

$f(x) = \sin(a) + b$

Therefore, if $x$ is not used the calculation of the result, can I still inverse this function to find $x$ for some $\sin(a) + b$?

Comment: Double check the function definition, this is unlikely.

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust, I've double checked, and I'm afraid that this is what's written on the question sheet I have.

Comment: Have they defined $a$ and $b$ anywhere else?

Comment: Mh, you should have said it was a homework, I would have commented differently.

Comment: @Element118, they have not, I think it's mean't to be the lengths of two sides of a right angled triangle: http://math2.org/math/algebra/functions/trig/.

Comment: @YvesDaoust not homework, left school long ago.

Comment: Is that source where the function came from? If so, the ratio is uniquely determined from $\theta$.

Comment: @Element118 No, it's just from my googling to try and figure out what a and b could possibly be in this context.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't invert this function.

Comment: ... because it's not one-to-one.